# Sort() Method For Similar Values

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am sorting an array using the `sort()` method. When there is a duplicate value I'd like to run secondary logic to decide the sort order.

For example, in the below array, I'd like to choose how `red` and `orange` get sorted.

This is my sorting function:

```
inventoryTally.sort(function (a, b) {

    if (a.inventoryTotal < b.inventoryTotal) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.inventoryTotal > b.inventoryTotal) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal) {
      //When inventory levels are the same, call secondary logic that further compares a and b based on sales volume of those 2 product variants
      //I want the variant with higher sales volume to be ordered first

      //My thinking is to dynamically return 1 or -1 so that the higher sales volume variant is ordered first
      //return 1;

    }
  });
```

When `a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal`, I'm testing between returning 1 and -1 in order to influence sort order. However, this does not change the order in which `red` and `orange` are sorted and has no influence on the array.

```
 [
   {
     option: 'Blue',
     inventoryTotal: 12312312,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Green',
     inventoryTotal: 1265,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Red',
     inventoryTotal: 3,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Orange',
     inventoryTotal: 3,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   }
 ]
```

I've stripped everything away to the basic function above and I think my issue is a fundamental misunderstanding of the `sort()` method.

Reading the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp), returning `1` or `-1` should reorder the array. However, it seems to ignore this return when the values are equal.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: Desired Outcome

When compared values are the same, I want to perform side calculations that ultimately return either -1 or 1. Depending on if 1 or -1 is returned, compared value order will be changed.

Return 1:

```
if (a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal) {
      return 1;
    }
```

```
 [
   {
     option: 'Blue',
     inventoryTotal: 12312312,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Green',
     inventoryTotal: 1265,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Red',
     inventoryTotal: 3,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Orange',
     inventoryTotal: 3,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   }
 ]
```

Return -1:

```
if (a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal) {
      return -1;
    }
```

```
 [
   {
     option: 'Blue',
     inventoryTotal: 12312312,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Green',
     inventoryTotal: 1265,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   {
     option: 'Orange',
     inventoryTotal: 3,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   }
   {
     option: 'Red',
     inventoryTotal: 3,
     variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
   },
   
 ]
```

EDIT 2: Further clarification around the initial function when `a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal`

Comment: Could you post an example of the result you want, and the result you are getting but don't want?

Comment: Also you should explain what you expect to happen when you return (a < b) and (b < a) for the same a,b (which is what returning -1 for equal items does)

Comment: I added an edit to my existing post with the desired outcome and more context. Does that help clarify? If not, i'm happy to add more information

Comment: Returning 1 when the values are equal is wrong.

Comment: red and orange have been reordered accordingly in your example output

Comment: @ArleighHix That's the desired outcome. Nothing changes currently when I test returning 1 or -1 when ```a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal```

Comment: @Pointy What about it is incorrect?

Comment: When sort keys are equal, the comparator should return 0. It is important to keep things consistent. There is no guarantee that any pair of keys will be consistently passed in the same order. If your function returns conflicting results for the same pair of keys, you may get weird results.

Comment: @InquisitiveTom I think the issue is that the sort function is only made to work with comparison functions that behave like a comparison function should. So that if comp(a,b) returns 1 comp(b,a) returns -1. Your provided sort function doesn't have this property and so it behaves in strange ways when applied. Also it is up to browsers to choose what sorting algo to use. On chrome I have found that if I sort [blue,green,red,orange] with returning -1 on ties it turns into [blue, green, orange, red]. What browser are you doing this in? And what is the initial input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `inventoryTotal` values are equal, then you should return a sort result based on doing a string comparison (using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)) of the two `option` values. If you want to sort alphabetically ('Orange' before 'Red'), use

```
a.option.localeCompare(b.option)
```

otherwise, use

```
b.option.localeCompare(a.option)
```

`localeCompare` will return either -1, 1, or 0 dependent on whether the reference string (`a.option` in the first example above) occurs before, after or is equal to the comparison string.

```js
const Variant = 'Variant'

const inventoryTally = [
  {
    option: 'Red',
    inventoryTotal: 3,
    variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
  },
  {
    option: 'Blue',
    inventoryTotal: 12312312,
    variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
  },
  {
    option: 'Orange',
    inventoryTotal: 3,
    variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
  },
  {
    option: 'Green',
    inventoryTotal: 1265,
    variant: [ [Variant], [Variant], [Variant] ]
  }
]

inventoryTally.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.inventoryTotal != b.inventoryTotal)
    // sort descending
    return b.inventoryTotal - a.inventoryTotal;
  else
    // sort ascending
    return a.option.localeCompare(b.option);
})

console.log(inventoryTally)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct, perhaps a more extensive example is needed?
Here's a working snippet:

```js
let inventoryTally = [{
    option: 'Blue',
    inventoryTotal: 1265,
    other: 5
  },
  {
    option: 'Green',
    inventoryTotal: 1265,
    other: 50
  },
  {
    option: 'Red',
    inventoryTotal: 3,
    other: 5
  },
  {
    option: 'Orange',
    inventoryTotal: 3,
    other: 50
  },
  {
    option: 'Blorange',
    inventoryTotal: 5555,
    other: 0
  }
]

inventoryTally.sort(function(a, b) {

  if (a.inventoryTotal < b.inventoryTotal) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.inventoryTotal > b.inventoryTotal) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal) {
    //When inventory levels are the same, call secondary logic that further compares a and b based on another property value
    if (a.other < b.other) return 1;
    if (b.other < a.other) return -1;
    return 0;
  }
});
console.log(inventoryTally)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works correctly and arranges the objects in the array in descending order based on inventoryTotal and the equality condition also works correctly. See the output of the following code:

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    option: 'Blue',
    inventoryTotal: 55,
  },
  {
    option: 'Green',
    inventoryTotal: 2,
  },
  {
    option: 'Red',
    inventoryTotal: 2,
  },
  {
    option: 'Orange',
    inventoryTotal: 88,
  }
];
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {

  if (a.inventoryTotal < b.inventoryTotal) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.inventoryTotal > b.inventoryTotal) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal) {
    if(a.option.length<b.option.length){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return -1;
    }

  }
});
console.log(myArray)
```

and compare with this:

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    option: 'Blue',
    inventoryTotal: 55,
  },
  {
    option: 'Green',
    inventoryTotal: 2,
  },
  {
    option: 'Reddd',
    inventoryTotal: 2,
  },
  {
    option: 'Orange',
    inventoryTotal: 88,
  }
];
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {

  if (a.inventoryTotal < b.inventoryTotal) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.inventoryTotal > b.inventoryTotal) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a.inventoryTotal === b.inventoryTotal) {
    if(a.option.length<b.option.length){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return -1;
    }

  }
});
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could return something like

```
a.option.localeCompare(b.option) * 2 - 1;
```

which compares, which string starts with the "higher" letter.

(Since the functions returns 0 or 1 the * 2 - 1 is needed)

Comment: You probably should explain why it is bad idea to return (a < b) and (b < a) for the same a,b (which is what returning -1 for equal items does)